# NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_equal' with minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest, assertions

I have testing structure below for automation testing.

```
#/project/class/Calculator.rb

require 'TestModule'
require 'MathOperation'

class Calculator
  include TestModule
  include MathOperation

  def initialize(num1, num2)
    @num1 = num1
    @num2 = num2
  end
end


#/project/methods/MathOperation.rb

module MathOperation
    def operation_addition
        addition = @num1 + @num2
        return addition
    end
end


#/project/methods/TestModule.rb

module TestModule
    def test_addition(value)
       assert_equal 25, value
    end   
end


#/project/tescases/TestCalculator.rb

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'calculator'

class TestCalculator < Minitest::Test

  def setup
    @calc = Calculator.new(15, 10)
  end

  def test_proper_addition
    resolution = @calc.operation_addition
    @calc.test_addition(resolution)
  end
end
```

When I execute test class TestCalculator I receive this error.

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'assert_equal' for #<Calculator:0x00000002a77518 @num1=15, @num2=10`

When I used `assert_equal` method in class `TestCalculator` it worked. But this way will cause in future long test cases and redundant code. How can I use "assertions" in module called by class with minitest? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand your design, but I can tell you that your testing code should be completely decoupled from your non-testing code. E.g. `Calculator` should not be including `TestModule`.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you mean decoupled. But if I remove `TestModule` from `Calculator` I can not call methods from `TestModule` with `Calculator` object. My problem is that the module `TestModule` can not use assert methods. But I am not ruby expert and maybe my design is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problems all come from your `TestModule` module. The meaning of this module is only clear if you look at all of the other code to understand it in context - this is a blatant violation of the principle of encapsulation. Why is the value 25 important? Why is the method called `test_addition` when the code is just asserting equality and not performing any addition? Remove that module entirely.

Then look at the examples in the [minitest documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest.html#module-MiniTest-label-Unit+tests) to see the intended usage. Let `Calculator` do all the work, while `TestCalculator` does the asserting:

```
# no testing code here, just functionality

module MathOperation
  def operation_addition
    addition = @num1 + @num2
  end
end

class Calculator
  include MathOperation

  def initialize(num1, num2)
    @num1 = num1
    @num2 = num2
  end
end

# and now we do all of the testing stuff

require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestCalculator < Minitest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @calc = Calculator.new(15, 10)
  end

  def test_addition
    assert_equal 25, @calc.operation_addition
  end
end
```

Comment: Does it mean that it is not possible use module as a tested part in my structure?
This is very simple example in which I wanted to describe my problem. I would like to use `minitest` for automation testing of web pages and if I will use it as you suggested then the maintenance of the framework will be very difficult and test cases will have a great amount of lines.  So I would like to separate testing of results into particular methods of some module.

Comment: You can still put the testing methods in a module if you want, just include that module in `TestCalculator` not `Calculator`.

Comment: I added 'include TestMethod` into `TestCalculator` but there are two errors now. The first is the same what I described above and the second is: `TestCalculator#test_addition:`
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` But I have proper number of arguments.

Comment: I don't mean that you can simply change your includes to get it to to work. _First_ restructure your code to look like my answer. _Then_ you can put `test_addition` in a module and include it. The argument error is because methods that start with `test_` are special to Minitest. Don't name a method that unless it's part of a test class (as in my answer).

Comment: I created the structure based on your answer and it works. But I mentioned it in my question after the code. This is not solution what I am looking for. I would like to send to you my specific code,is it possible? Because I feel that this way is quite long for stackoverflow usage. I will leave your possible solution here as a result.

Comment: You could start a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) and paste the link in the comments here. Then we can work out the issue you're having.